# Dynamically adding/removing FeatureGroup to/from the Layer Control?

Tags: leaflet

I am currently using leaflet.draw plugin to draw polygons and lines.  The plugin depends on FeatureGroup for storing and editing.  I want to manage these geometries (e.g. turn their visibility on or off) like those in the layer control.

Ultimately, I want to be able to add and remove these FeatureGroups.

Is this achievable?

### Additional Information (thanks to iH8 for commenting and sorry for the lack of details):

Here is what I want to achieve:
1. Treat FeatureGroup like dynamic layers (can add or remove or edit).  It is where I can draw geometries and place markers
2. When a FeatureGroup is added, it should be in the Layer Control so user can turn the visibility on or off.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is easily do-able if you want **all** the features created through Leaflet.draw plugin to be in the same Feature Group, and to be able to turn it on/off as a whole, not single features independently. Otherwise, that would get more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. You can add any type of layer to `L.Control.Layers`, that also means grouping layers:

```
new L.Control.Layers(null, {
    'Markers': new L.FeatureGroup([
        new L.Marker([45, 0]),
        new L.Marker([-45, 0]),
        new L.Marker([0, 45]),
        new L.Marker([0, -45])
    ]),
    'Polylines': new L.FeatureGroup([
        new L.Polyline([[-45, -45], [45, 45]]),
        new L.Polyline([[45, -45], [-45, 45]])
    ])
}).addTo(map);
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/6mC6HTfPmzG9AblK1wyg?p=preview

Comment: I am using the leaflet angular directive and wanted to treat FeatureGroup like "layer" which can be turn on and off.  I also wanted to do this dynamically, i.e. create/delete FeatureGroup layer

Comment: Well, things like that you should've mentioned in your question. Then when people take the time and effort to answer your question they have all the facts and requirements so they don't waste their time and effort on an answer which is of no use to you. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask The question was: can you put a featuregroup into the layercontrol. The answer is yes and i even gave you an example. I'de suggest you put more effort in a new proper question.